# How would I make a simple encryption/decryption program?

Tags: python, encryption, tkinter

I'd like to know (just as the question says) how to make a simple encryption and decryption program.

`letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
 encryption_code = 'LFWOAYUISVKMNXPBDCRJTQEGHZ'`

I'd like the latter section to be what the letters of the alphabet are encrypted to and if the user chooses the decrypt it, I'd like it to be reversed or reverted back into the alphabet form.

Is this too complicated because from the examples I've looked over, all they seem to do is shift the alphabet 3 or 4 spaces and use that as their encryption code.

Comment: Is there a webpage or something where I can read over about that?

Comment: You could also just convert each letter to its corresponding number in the alphabet minus one and that's the index of the encryption/decryption string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two dicts to do the mapping, one from letters to encryption_code and the reverse to decrypt:

```
letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
encryption_code = 'LFWOAYUISVKMNXPBDCRJTQEGHZ'

enc = dict(zip(letters,encryption_code))

dec = dict(zip(encryption_code, letters))


s = "HELLO WORLD"

encr = "".join([enc.get(ch, ch) for ch in s])
decr = "".join([dec.get(ch, ch) for ch in encr])

print(encr)
print(decr)
```

Output:

```
IAMMP EPCMO 
HELLO WORLD
```

Using your method your input will have to be uppercase and the user is restricted to A-Z for the letters to be encrypted, if you want to allow other characters just add the mapping to the dicts.

```
letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
encryption_code = 'LFWOAYUISVKMNXPBDCRJTQEGHZ'
letters += letters.lower()
encryption_code += encryption_code.lower()
enc = dict(zip(letters,encryption_code))

dec = dict(zip(encryption_code, letters))


s = "HELLO world"

encr = "".join([enc.get(ch, ch) for ch in s])
decr = "".join([dec.get(ch, ch) for ch in encr])

print(encr)
print(decr)
```

Output:

```
IAMMP epcmo
HELLO world
```

Any characters not in letters will be the same in encr and decr i.e:

```
 s = "HELLO world!#}%"
 IAMMP epcmo!#}% # encr
 HELLO world!#}% # decr
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly now!

Comment: No prob, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

you create an encoder and a decoder:

```
enc = str.maketrans(letters, encryption_code)
dec = str.maketrans(encryption_code, letters)
```

and use them:

```
encr = 'HELLO WORLD'.translate(enc)
decr = encr.translate(dec)
```