# python encryption with a cipher

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I need to encrypt a string in python according to a cipher.

```
character_set = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "
secret_key    = "Dd18Abz2EqNPW hYTOjBvtVlpXaH6msFUICg4o0KZwJeryQx3f9kSinRu5L7cGM"
```

any ideas? my function always returns a long list like:

```
2
e
4
4
```

code:

```
import string

def my_encryption(s):        
    s.translate(str.maketrans(character_set, secret_key))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I make a simple encryption/decryption program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221559/how-would-i-make-a-simple-encryption-decryption-program)

Comment: in python 3 see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in python 2

```
>>> import string
>>> translate_table = string.maketrans(character_set, secret_key)
>>> string.translate("test", translate_table)
'BAjB'
```

in python 3:

```
>>> "test".translate(str.maketrans(character_set, secret_key))
'BAjB'
```

or manually in python 3:

```
>>> D = dict(zip(character_set, secret_key))
>>> ''.join(map(D.get, "test"))
'BAjB'
```

Comment: type str has no attr maketrans

Comment: it has, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans do you use python 3 or python 2?

Comment: python 3, but in edX, not a full python lib

Comment: not really, and I guess you want to return something from your function, where do you define `character_set` and `secret_key`? I would like to see the whole code

Comment: character_set = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 "
secret_key         = "Dd18Abz2EqNPW hYTOjBvtVlpXaH6msFUICg4o0KZwJeryQx3f9kSinRu5L7cGM"

Comment: I added a version not using `maketrans`

Comment: could you take a look at my other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678327/python-spell-checker ?